# Modal popups in ASP.NET AJAX in IE9 not working

Tags: asp.net-ajax, internet-explorer-9, modalpopupextender

Fighting with this for few days in a row - no luck. Trying to make ModalPopupExtender work with IE9. I use latest AjaxControlToolki.dll Version 50731 both for .NET 3.5 and 4.0. And wondering btw when IE will finally disappear from the face of Earth??? Help please!!!!
      Also - adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9">` to master page's `<head>` tag helps with popups but messes the layout and since it's in master page, messes whole website so can't use this solution. It's clear that IE9 CSS handling and so called "compatibility mode" is the reason for this damn issue - HOW TO FIX IT!!! PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: If its running in your intranet - IE9 will always default to compatibility mode. Which is why I am guessing adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9">` works for you. However if this messes your layout, it could mean your layout style properties are not compatible with IE9 or any of the modern browsers. Is your web page working on Chrome or Safari?

Comment: Everything is ok in latest FF and Chrome. Without the meta tag layout looks as expected and everything else is ok in IE9 - EXCEPT popups. With tag - popups are fine in all browsers - but master page layout is totally messed in all browsers. We can't target just IE9 cause it's 20% of users and btw the share is steadily shrinking to my great pleasure. Still 20% of users is too many to ignore so I'm trying to find solution. Btw it's always like that with IE - u always have to spend 50%-80% of time extra to make things work in IE.

Comment: tag `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9"` shouldn't affect any other browsers. It is only for IE purposes. By the way try this tag instead `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly your problem is without setting up the whole Ajax.Net control but what if you went with jQuery Dialog / Modal instead? I've used it with great success.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: The problem is that popup window is not actually a popup but appears below the calling control with totally messed layout. We can't use jQuery because we use Prototype and there is a lot of existing code, and due to conflicts we can't. This is a known problem with IE9 and ASP.NET AJAX - there are some workarounds - unfortunately none of them work for me.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx this is the tool you are using correct? The demo example runs for me on their site in IE9. I guess my only option from here would be to setup a test project and install Ajax.NET toolkit to look at your issue. Have you still not been able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem, my issue is now resolved when I added the following meta tag in the master page head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

Comment: Yes - known fix, unfortunately it brakes a lot of layout css in the same time, so be aware:)